# What exactly does the br_netfilter kernel module control?

Tags: iptables, kernel-modules, bridge

I'm trying to get a clear understanding of what exactly the `br_netfilter` Linux kernel module does (I know it has something to do with networking).

My simple question I'm posing here is as follows:

What is an example of something I CAN do with this module enabled which I CAN NOT do when it is disabled? I had thought it had something to do with `iptables`, but when disabling/enabling the module I was always able to run the same `iptables` commands.

Note: since I wasn't positive that I wouldn't kill my computer by disabling a kernel module, I created a test AWS EC2 instance to test this.

EDIT:
To clarify, what I would like to see is a simple set of steps, aka, run X, Y, Z commands, which when enabled, system acts as expected, when disabled, it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in order for that module to be of any use to you, you must first be *bridging* traffic between two or more network interfaces (physical or virtual).

For example, if you want to run QEMU/KVM virtual machines on your system and to be able to present the virtual machines to the network as separate IP addresses (= no port forwarding needed to set up services in VMs), you could run a bridge between the physical network interface of your host system and the virtual network interfaces of your VMs.

Or if you wish to run `hostapd` to make your own WiFi access point and don't want the wireless network to be a separate IP subnet, you would run a bridge between the wired and wireless network interfaces.

Basically, once the output of `brctl show` or `ip link show type bridge` is not an empty list, you'll be in a position to use `ebtables` to set up restrictions on the traffic passing through the bridge(s), based on MAC addresses.

If those two commands show no output, `br_netfilter` will be of no use to you, because you are not using the subsystem which `br_netfilter` would be filtering. And even if they *do* show output, if all you need is MAC-based filtering on your bridges, then you still don't need the `br_netfilter` module at all.

But what if you want to do filtering by IP addresses or TCP/UDP ports in your bridge? Then you could run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables`. **This is what enables the `br_netfilter` module** and allows you to apply `iptables` rules to bridged traffic too.

Untested example, assuming I've understood it correctly:

You are running a virtualization host, which runs a KVM virtual machine that has a virtual network interface named `vifX` as seen from the host. The virtual networking is implemented using a bridge `br0`, to which is attached both the physical interface `eno1` and the virtual interface `vifX`. The VM has IP address/mask 10.6.6.6/24. Within the same network segment, directly reachable via `eno1`, there is another physical server with IP address/mask 10.6.6.100/24.

Initially, SSH connections can be established from 10.6.6.100 to 10.6.6.6 and vice versa. You would like to allow connections from 10.6.6.100 to 10.6.6.6, but block outgoing SSH connections from 10.6.6.6.

You'd make the standard connection-tracking iptables FORWARD rules, by network interface:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i vifX -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i vifX -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
```

But initially it does not work, because you are not *routing* the traffic between the VM and the outside world; you are *bridging*. So, you enable `br_netfilter` to apply the `iptables` rules to bridged traffic too:

```
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

Now the physical host 10.6.6.100 can SSH into the VM 10.6.6.6, but the VM cannot make outgoing SSH connections to port 22 anywhere. Not even to other hosts in the same network segment.

More info about `ebtables` here: https://ebtables.netfilter.org/index.html

Specifically about `br_netfilter` and how to enable it: https://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html